# Unable to edit JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net

I can't figure out why this JSON updating method isn't working. I'm able to import my JSON file but not save it back. I'm wondering what is the issue. The JSON is very simple; just two values to BearsVersion.json

```
{
"test1":"HELLO",
"test2":"WORLD"
}
```

The line to call this method is:

```
 await FileHelper.UpdateVersions("./BearsVersion.json", "test1", "ADDING SUCCESSFUL");
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace UpdateJsonTest
{

    public class FileHelper
    {
        
        public static async Task? UpdateVersions(string jsonFilePath, string specificKey, string newValue)
        {
            try
            {
                // Read the entire JSON file
                string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);

                // Deserialize JSON to a dictionary
                Dictionary<string, object> jsonDictionary = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);

                if (jsonDictionary != null && jsonDictionary.ContainsKey(specificKey))
                {
                    // Update the specific key with the new value
                    jsonDictionary[specificKey] = newValue;

                    // Serialize the updated dictionary back to JSON
                    string updatedJsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonDictionary, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });

                    // Write the updated JSON back to the file
                    File.WriteAllText(jsonFilePath, updatedJsonString);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Key '{specificKey}' has been updated with the value '{newValue}' in the JSON file.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Key '{specificKey}' does not exist in the JSON file or the file is empty.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Troubleshooting:

1. When I run this method, I get the success message ("$"Key '{specificKey}' has been updated with the value '{newValue}' in the JSON file.") and Dictionary has been set to the sepcific new value. So the File.WriteAllText is failing.

Comment: Hi, Please provide a [mcve]. Also what is happening? Is there an error message?

Comment: Are the values of updatedJsonString and  jsonString what you expect? Did the changedate of the file change? Any errors (please specify as edit to your post)? Did you use the debugger to step through your code to see what is happening?

Comment: So Sorry @NineBerry. Added additional info and troubleshooting done

Comment: "./BearsVersion.json" is a relative path. You are probably looking at the wrong directory. Look in the directory where the executable file is created.

Comment: Does your app have permission to write to `jsonFilePath`?  Is it open and locked by another app?  What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  You can get the full `ToString()` by doing `Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred:\n{ex}");`

Comment: I'm able to use your code to change the json content both in a console app and an mvc app(just change the path of the file and you mentioned that you can import the file so it's not a path issue). do you met any exception when you run your code? my test result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps5iz.png  and https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey2cL.png

Comment: I tried out your code in linqpad and it worked fine for me. The only thing I updated was the file path passed in to point to my version of your file.  I feel like we must be missing some detail.

Comment: @dbc I think it's the write permission issue since the updatedJsonString is updating

Comment: @dbc DO you have any tips on updating the write or updating it to thread safe? I ran my Visual Studio as an admin and still ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Fix: The relative path was saving to the debug folder. Using the Absolute path forced WriteAllText to save to the appropriate folder.